# node Invalid regular expression flags javascript library in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a module written in plain javascript and am trying to import this module into an node application written in typescript, but one of the codes in the javascript module is throwing this error.

```
b = s.matchAll(/<FILE_INCLUDE [^>]+>/gid);
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags
```

is there anything that i need to do to fix this error?

Comment: I am betting it is complaining about `d`. What version of Node are you running?

Comment: i am using node 14.

Comment: I know in node 14, matchAll() is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the `d` flag, which has only been available since node@16.0.0
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/hasIndices#browser_compatibility

So it results in a Syntax Error on node versions below that

---

Unless you are working on a legacy project which could break when updating node, update node to the current LTS version, 18
https://nodejs.dev/en/about/releases/